# Location History

Tags: google, maps, location-services

Coming from Android I really miss location history (nee Latitude), is there anything on WP that serves a similar function? (Since [the Latitude API has been retired](https://developers.google.com/latitude/) any apps that used to update Google Latitude itself may not work any more.)

**UPDATE:** I have now found [Phone Tracker](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/phone-tracker/1b3e9546-98f6-449d-ac95-a06c139dfcac) which does the job very well.

Comment: Hi, application recommendations are off-topic. Perhaps you could reword it to ask if it is technically possible for an application to provide similar functionality on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way on WP to guarantee that an app is always running. And there's no way in WP to launch a program on startup. Therefore, is there no reliable way to do what you're doing. Certain apps *can* track your location if you start them up and make certain that they're always running (manually), but the app can be shut down at any time by the operating system.

Comment: If you are using Windows Phone 8, apps that are on the homescreen can bypass some of the restrictions to background processes. This means that you do not have to make sure you open it up occasionally. Other background processes stop if you do not open the app for two weeks, not pinned apps. They will also restart automatically if you restart your phone. True someone could go in and turn off a background process for an app, but that would be on purpose. The only other limitation is for low memory phones, they have limited total background processes including pinned apps.

Comment: Yes, but I still don't agree that WP provides a _reliable_ means of tracking location, and it's definitely not possible for WP to, reliably and constantly, collect finer gained location information such as every 20 seconds.

Comment: Windows Phone apps can "reliably" collect location data. They cannot do it at that resolution without the app constantly running. Android allows that ability at the detrimental user experience of the phone. If any app could do that all the time. Battery life would be atrocious and it would use processing cycles that other apps need causing a slow, sluggish phone.

Comment: In my opinion, something isn't reliable if it requires me, an inherently unreliable man, to intervene at regular intervals. 

The user didn't specify anything about battery life. And, in fact, my Garmin 62s can track much higher resolution than my phone will, and constantly, and for much longer than my phone battery will last.

Comment: My point is you DON'T have to intervene with the app I recommended. If its on the home page it just works, if you don't pin it it'll tell you what to do in a timely manner. I brought up battery life to explain why you can't constatnly track every second of your life. And bringing up a dedicated GPS to this conversation means nothing. It's a dedicated device that you would never use to track yourself 24/7 and if you did, you'd still run into the problems I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, you DO have to intervene with the app you recommended. One of the first things the app says when you run it is that you have to run it every 14 days or it will stop logging your location, even if you pin it. And if an app has to tell you to do something periodically to keep it running, that's called intervention. Also, you most certainly can keep track of yourself 24/7 with a dedicated device. Anyone who has every had a real GPS (Such as a 62S) most likely has this kind of expectation when they get a "smart phone" with a GPS as well.

Comment: Read the Constraints for all Schedlued Task Types --> Reschedule required every two weeks. It explains the exceptions to the two week cycle. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx The app reminds you everytwo weeks dumbly because it cannot detect if it is pinned. Nor do many people understand even after it is explained to them.

Answer (score 1):

[Track My Life](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=597fc829-74ae-4856-832a-a4daddb73ee8) is an app that has features I believe you are asking for. It periodically takes your location and present this on a map with other statistics about how long you are at each location and how often.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to want £2.50 for backing up the data to SkyDrive though, and I'm if I can get to the data even then.